# SQL Server port

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, port, sql-server-2012

I have more than one instance of SQL Server installed on my PC (actually, one 2005, one 2008 and one 2012). All of them running. I realized that all of them are configured (SQL Server Configuration Manager ->  SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for the Database Engine -> TCP/IP) to run on port 1433.

How is it possible?

Comment: Have you confirmed that both are actively running?  If they are, then you likely don't have TCP/IP enabled on one of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible. You can read the errorlog to find your allocated port number for each server..Do a netstat on the command prompt to list the connections. this will also show what is the port number for each connection.